# References on tilting distributions using $\frac{d \overline{\mathbb{P}}}{d \mathbb{P}} = \frac{g(X)}{E(g(X))} $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request

I came across the idea of **tilting** probability distributions in a course on Measure Theory, however, when trying to research this topic further, I haven't managed to find anything online.

There are many references to specific distributions that have been tilted (most notably the titled exponential distribution), however, I am interested in looking at tilted distributions in generality rather than any specific examples of tilted distributions.

My lecture course uses the following notion of tilted distributions:

> Consider the measure space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and the non-negative measurable function $g$ such that $E(g(X)) < \infty $. Then we can define a new measure $\overline{\mathbb{P}}$ where we define the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d \overline{\mathbb{P}}}{d \mathbb{P}} = \frac{g(X)}{E(g(X))}$. The distribution of $X$ under this new measure $\overline{\mathbb{P}}$ is biased by the function $g$.

Are there any papers, books, or general reading material on this idea that someone could redirect me towards? I would be interested in exploring this idea further but have been unable to find anything of use so far.

Comment: This is more or less just a probability density function, but with respect to a general measure instead of just the Lebesgue measure. I have never heard the word "tilted" used in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The survey paper [Size bias for one and all](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2729) gives the general definition of **tilting** in Section $2.1$ on page $4$.

After the definition and basic properties are established, the following is stated (perhaps explaining why I encountered reference to the process of exponential tilting so often in my research):

> The class of exponential functions, $h(x)=e^{\beta  x}$ for various choices of $\beta \in
> (-\infty,\infty)$, is very important.  This class is  central to exponential families and large deviation
> theory, but no single value $\beta$ plays a special role.
> The family of power functions $h(x)=x^\beta$ for $\beta>0$ might be viewed as  runner up, behind the family of exponential functions, but here the  choice $\beta=1$ is truly special. We believe that $h(x)=x$  for $x \ge 0$ is *the most important* example of bias.

Note that here they use the notation $h(x)$ as opposed to $g(x)$ as used in the original question.